# Configuration dconf Editor How To to get Settings - > Displays to Work

Tags: 16.04, display, configuration, settings

One of my Boxes’ Post Upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS the System Setting - > Displays gives "Could not get screen information". On the same Box when signed in a “Guest”  Settings - > Displays shows Perfect, so in some config in that user got screwed up during the upgrade.

I Goggled and checked Ask Ubuntu. Best I found where obsolete answer or answers that lack explicit details on how the configure Settings - > Displays.

So How exactly what to set / do in  dconf Editor or some other way to Configure whatever so Setting - > Displays to work correctly.

Comment: First thing I'd always try: remove `~/.config/monitors.xml`, immediately log out and back in.

Comment: I assumed the problem is in that users’ ~/Home since When logged in as Guest Setting - > Displays gives id correct. I Check with that user /Home. No such file in ~/.config. searched /Home for “ monitors.xml” no such file.